# Ruby 2.2.3 invalid date

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

The following method

```
now = Date.today
@start_week = Date.commercial(now.cwyear,now.cweek+9)
```

is returning and argument error `invalid date`.  This was working under ruby 1.9.3. Oddly enough, there are no complaints regarding

```
@start_week = Date.commercial(now.cwyear,now.cweek+8)
```

and the console returns `Mon, 28 Dec 2015`

So the issue is how does one concisely rollover the year in such a context.

Comment: Well, that first date is out of range. It's not possible in the current year. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Yes, just realized that.  Got fooled in some testing which allowed the +9 to pass in the midst of other evaluations. And edited the question

Comment: You meant "how", not "who"? :)

Comment: ah yes.  I'm firing my coffee maker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly.  Transform the method to a succinct

```
@start_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week + 9.weeks
```

*[get percolator running]*